# Serializing multiple levels in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am running a django application and I want to return a big JSON for my model structure. The problem is I always get the following error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field fourth_highest_objects on serializer ThirdHighestSerializer. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the ModelThirdHighest instance. Original exception text was: 'ModelThirdHighest' object has no attribute 'fourth_highest_objects'.

My model structure is a bit complex:

```
class ModelHighest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,
    )


class ModelSecondHighest(models.Model):
 
    model_highest = models.ManyToManyField(
        ModelHighest,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )
    model_third_highest = models.ManyToManyField(
        ModelThirdHighest,
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )


class ModelThirdHighest(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Now inheritance comes into play:

```
class ModelSuper(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = False

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=120,
    )

    

class ModelFourthHighest(ModelSuper):
       
    third_highest_relation = models.ForeignKey(
        ModelThirdHighest,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="fourth_highest_objects",
    )
```

What I want is a big nested JSON of everything:

```
├── ModelHighest
    ├── ModelSecondHighest
        ├── ModelThirdHighest
           ├── ModelFourthdHighest
```

I can get until `ModelThirdHighest` but I can't serialize the last one. My serializers look like this:

```
class FourthHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    class Meta:
        model = ModelFourthHighest
        fields = (
            "name"
        )


class ThirdHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    fourth_highest_objects = FourthHighestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelThirdHighest
        fields = (
            "name",
            "fourth_highest_objects",
        )



class SecondHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    model_third_highest = ThirdHighestSerializer(
        many=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ModelSecondHighest
        fields = (
            "name",
            "model_third_highest",
        )


class HighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer with all information."""

    model_second_highest_set = ModelHighestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelHighest
        fields = (
            "project_name",
            "model_second_highest_set"
        )
```

Now I know that the error is thrown in the `ThirdHighestSerializer` with the field `fourth_highest_objects`. Again, it throws me the error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `fourth_highest_objects` on serializer `ThirdHighestSerializer`.
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `ModelThirdHighest` instance.
> Original exception text was: 'ModelThirdHighest' object has no attribute 'fourth_highest_objects'.

But I was quite sure that I have to use the related name for the reverse relation. What am I doing wrong? Can I even serialize down to those levels?

Thanks in advance to anyone who finds the patience to read through this. I know it's a bit tricky, I tried to explain as best as I could. I can clarify if needed.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT1:

Even when I change the code to:

```
  fourth_highest_objects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_fourth_highest_objects(self, obj):
        print(obj)
        return FourthHighestSerializer(obj.fourth_highest_objects.all(), many=True).data
```

I get the error that `ModelThirdHighest` has no attribute fourth_highest_objects`, yet in the shell I can do` ModelThirdHighest.objecst.last().fourth_highest_objects.all()` without a problem

EDIT2: Even stranger:

When I do `print(dir(obj))` in the serializer I do not get the field `fourth_highest_objects`

But when I go to my shell I do have the field....

So I guess the problem is that the field is missing in the serializer. But how can this happen, it is not clear at all to me...

Comment: get fetch user model_a.model_b.Model_c.model_d this will be you a get required data in nested way.

Comment: @ShahVipul Thank you for your help! Would you mind explaining this a bit more? What do you mean with `get fetch user model_a....`?

Comment: You want nested json.So,by calling one table data and ManyToManyField and fk you can call another model data.
ex 
----
model a:
  flName = name()
model b:
  name = fk(a)
  age  = intigerFiled()
-------
so by accessing model b you can also access model a
model_b.model_a.flName

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear to me. Do you mean on the serializer or where?? I get the error on `fourth_highest_objects = FourthHighestSerializer(many=True)`.... I can't see how I should call the table data here instead

Comment: should call the table data here instead - YES 
The convert it to JSON and pass it to serializer.

Comment: still not sure if I get it. But let's say I hardcode it to `fourth_highest_objects={"12":"12"}` I still get the error 'ModelThirdHighest' object has no attribute 'fourth_highest_objects'.

Comment: convert manytomany to foreignKey .just try it.

Comment: I am still on this but had to make a break. I still don't understand how I should "convert manytomany to foreignKey". I tried passing various datasets to the serializer but always get the same error. I think it might be connected to the inherited model structure. According to documentation I should define the serializer and use as field the reverse relation.

Comment: just upload your code to github and share a link.
I will take a look at it.

Comment: Please also see my edits. I think the problem is that there is a field missing at the serializer level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# serializer.py
class FourthHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    class Meta:
        model = ModelFourthHighest
        fields = (
            "name",
        )


class ThirdHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    fourth_highest_objects = FourthHighestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelThirdHighest
        fields = (
            "name",
            "fourth_highest_objects",
        )


class SecondHighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """..."""

    model_third_highest = ThirdHighestSerializer(
        many=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ModelSecondHighest
        fields = (
            "model_third_highest",
        )


class HighestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializer with all information."""

    modelsecondhighest_set = SecondHighestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelHighest
        fields = (
            "name",
            "modelsecondhighest_set"
        )
```

### Usage

```
import json

serializer = HighestSerializer(ModelHighest.objects.first())
result = json.dumps(serializer.data, indent=4)
print(result)

{
    "name": "Model highest - 1",
    "modelsecondhighest_set": [
        {
            "model_third_highest": [
                {
                    "name": "some name",
                    "fourth_highest_objects": [
                        {
                            "name": "some other name"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: thank you. So, are you saying that my code is working for you and that there must be something wrong with my model setup?

Comment: I would say, "almost working", but some typos. You can check the [**git diff here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCcQG.png) to what I have changed.

Comment: that's very odd indeed then. But good to know the structure is correct..... Because in my code I don't have those typos. Ss I posted in my edits the field is missing in the serializer but it exists when I try it in the shell.... I'm very confused now

Comment: You have typo, it shoudl be **`modelsecondhighest_set`** instead of `model_second_highest_set`

Comment: Yes here on stackoverflow I have a typo but not in my original code...

Comment: I tried and solved the issue by using the ***"given code snippet"***. Better you [add a  ,minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing your OP.

Comment: The problem was caused by another model that had the same name and did not have the field. Thank you very much for directing me into the right direction, really appreciated!!

Comment: Giving you the bounty when SO let's me (in about 1h)